# How to annotate TikZ plotted function using axis values?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, csv

I would like to annotate local max of a .csv spectrum. My goal is to have a latex plot analogous of the matplotlib script I use, which give me this result:
[image]

I've plotted the same spectrum from [this .csv file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9O7sxdAf2xjcjdLaTNYaG5aMXc/edit?usp=sharing) using latex:

[image]

Now supposing I know the coordinates of the peaks (e.g. for the **first peak 801.3,6066**) how can I annotate the peeks with an arrow like the matplotlib version.
Of course I can use:

```
\draw [<-] (30,450) -- (40,460);
```

But for me these number means nothing, I have to try many times to find the correct values. I would like instead use the plot's reference system so I can write e.g. for the first peak:

```
\draw [<-] (801.3,6066) -- (821.3,6086);
```

How can I switch to it?

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[line width = 0.5pt] table [mark=none,col sep=comma,] {cicloexane.csv};
\draw [<-] (30,450) -- (40,460);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use `(axis cs:x,y)` as point:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
\addplot[line width = 0.5pt] table [mark=none,col sep=comma,] {cicloexane.csv};
\draw [<-] (axis cs:801.3,6066)-- +(10pt,10pt) node[right] {here};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any possibility to parse the coordinates for the draw command from the csv-file (e.g. by specifying the row)?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `draw`, `path` or `node` configurations to annotate plot coordinates, also you can use `pin` option for nodes and configure it to your requirements.

Here an example:

## Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}%http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots

\newcommand\annotate[1]{\drawannotate(#1)}%Command to produce annotations based on path
\def\drawannotate(#1,#2){
    \path (axis cs:#1,#2)-- +(5pt,5pt) node[rotate=60,scale=.3,pos=.25] {\textless} node[font=\tiny] {#2};
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[ymax = 7000]
            \addplot[line width = 0.5pt] table [mark=none,col sep=comma] {cicloexane.csv};
            \annotate{801.345,6116}%Using the command, argument are coordinates
            \annotate{1028.607,3106}
            \annotate{1157.473,2076}
            \annotate{1266.954,2942}
            \annotate{1444.418,2648}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \tikzset{pin distance=6pt, every pin edge/.style={<-,shorten >=-2pt,shorten <=-3pt}, every pin/.append style={font=\tiny}}%Setting pin style
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[ymax = 7000]
            \addplot[line width = 0.5pt] table [mark=none,col sep=comma] {cicloexane.csv};
            \node[font=\tiny,pin= above right:{6116}] at (axis cs:801.345,6116) {};
            \node[font=\tiny,pin= above right:{3106}] at (axis cs:1028.607,3106) {};
            \node[font=\tiny,pin= above:{2076}] at (axis cs:1157.473,2076) {};
            \node[font=\tiny,pin= above right:{2942}] at (axis cs:1266.954,2942) {};
            \node[font=\tiny,pin= above right:{2648}] at (axis cs:1444.418,2648) {};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Result

[image]

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot this answer is awesome! I would like to mark both as accepted answer...